# On page load, error, getAll is not defined. I believe it is defined?

Tags: javascript, html

Upon my page loading, I get the following error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: getAll is not defined at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>`

I'm trying to trigger a modal. When someone clicks the Watch Video button. The `<div id="modal" class="modal">` changes to `<div id="modal" class="modal is-active">`.

My Javascript is as follows:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  // Modals

  var rootEl = document.documentElement;
  var $modals = getAll('.modal');
  var $modalButtons = getAll('.modal-button');
  var $modalCloses = getAll('.modal-background, .modal-close, .modal-card-head .delete, .modal-card-foot .button');

  if ($modalButtons.length > 0) {
     $modalButtons.forEach(function ($el) {
        $el.addEventListener('click', function () {
          var target = $el.dataset.target;
          openModal(target);
        });
     });
  }

  if ($modalCloses.length > 0) {
     $modalCloses.forEach(function ($el) {
        $el.addEventListener('click', function () {
          closeModals();
        });
     });
  }

  function openModal(target) {
     var $target = document.getElementById(target);
     rootEl.classList.add('is-clipped');
     $target.classList.add('is-active');
  }

  function closeModals() {
     rootEl.classList.remove('is-clipped');
     $modals.forEach(function ($el) {
        $el.classList.remove('is-active');
     });
  }

  document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
     var e = event || window.event;
     if (e.keyCode === 27) {
        closeModals();
        closeDropdowns();
     }
 });
});
```

My `getAll` are all linked to css classes? Hence why I believe they are defined?

[CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/grantsmith/pen/pOjomK)

Comment: getAll does not exist. Instead use `document.querySelectorAll()`

Comment: Why do you believe `getAll()` is defined? Where do you define it?

Comment: I don't see any function named `getAll` !

Comment: You are referencing a function called `getAll()` as soon as the document is loaded, but you do not have any such function declared, hence the error. If you believe that such a function is part of the native API, you are mistaken, `document.querySelecorAll()` is.

Comment: Ok, so I am misunderstanding what the getAll does in this statement `var $modals = getAll('.modal');`

Comment: Maybe not what it does, but certainly how to use it. You can't call functions that you don't have declarations for.